# Vue / Vuetify / Laravel - Storing multiple file input

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to store multiple files to my local storage uploaded by a user. I don't know how I would store it and bind it with the `id` of the user. I am getting the array files from my `data` but I'm only up to that point. I'm sorry that I need help on this one.

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="tableItem.files"
  small-chips 
  multiple 
  placeholder="Select file..."
  dense
/>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableItem {
        files: [],
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
  async save() {
    try {
      let res = await axios.post('/api/positions', this.tableItem)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You upload it to your storage and save the file path in the database with a user id. There are many ways to do it and it really depends on your application requirements.

Comment: I'm trying a lot of tutorials and would probably combine each one of them. I just need a simple where all these files belongs to an `id`